# PHP test whether remote MySQL server is available

Tags: php, mysql

I have some websites that uses MySQL. I'm not expert in SQL, so I use simple connection, querys, etc.. Sometimes (is rare but happens) only the database server hangs, or I forgot to turn on my home testing mysql. Until it operational again, the server hangs trying to connect and finally a timeout error happens.

I'm trying to add some previous test of database server like this "ping" function:

```
function pingDomain($domain){
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    $file = fsockopen ($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $stoptime = microtime(true);
    $status = 0;

    if (!$file) {
        $status = -1; // Site is down
    } else {
        fclose($file);
        $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
        $status = floor($status);
    }

    return $status;
}
```

But didn't work either, php hangs anyway. Any ideas?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting?  What behavior are you experiencing? It looks like this script should block (hang) for 10 seconds.  If your server timeout is 10 seconds or less than the whole script will timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't find anywhere a documentation about a reliable and simple test about mySQL server. I'm using now the following technique:

```
@$this->Base = mysqli_init();
@$this->Base->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1);
@$this->Base->real_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd);
```

Than you catch the error with $this->Base->connect_error or $this->Base->connect_errno, it will not be written because of "@" symbols.

You may use procedural form as well:

```
$Link = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($Link, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$res = @mysqli_real_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd);
if($res) {
    $E->echop("Connected!!!");
} else {
    $E->echop("Huston, we got a problem...");
}
```

Comments and other answers are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Simple use mysql_ping:

```
            <?php
            set_time_limit(0);

            $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysqluser', 'mypass');
            $db   = mysql_select_db('mydb');

            /* Assuming this query will take a long time */
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$result) {
                echo 'Query #1 failed, exiting.';
                exit;
            }

            /* Make sure the connection is still alive, if not, try to reconnect */
            if (!mysql_ping($conn)) {
                echo 'Lost connection, exiting after query #1';
                exit;
            }
            mysql_free_result($result);

            /* So the connection is still alive, let's run another query */
            $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
            ?>
```

You may want to take a look at this:

[mysql_ping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php)

Comment: +1 Though preferably [mysqli::ping()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php) these days, [mysql extension is soon to be deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

Comment: It doesn't work. As I read, set_time_limit complements the timeout set in php.ini (usually set as 30s), so it still hang for a looong time. But I thinking about this kind of approach: a quick error to detect that there is no connection.

Comment: @Orbling Soon? Tomorrow? Next week? Even in PHP 6 mysql_connect will If it doesn't I'll write you myself the functions as wrapper over the mysqli ;)

Comment: @GTodorov: Provision of a facility, does not mean it is not frowned upon.  There are reasons for the change being pushed.  I think the mysql extension functions are to issue `E_DEPRECATED` warnings by version 6, earlier possibly.

Comment: The update is after 5.4+ but the extension will be still available.